# How to remove duplicate data in JavaScript RowDataPacket Array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got a data from my MySQL Server with Nodejs and I want to remove duplicate data in this array, but the structure of the array looks weird and I tried various method to solve this problem but, it's useless.

**Code**

```
router.get(`/find-users/:queryString`, function(req, res, next) {
  let queryString = req.params.queryString;
  db.query(
    `SELECT userId from project WHERE keyword like "%${queryString}%"`,
    function(error, data) {
      // console.log(Array.from(new Set(data)));
      console.log(data);
    }
  );
  res.json(data);
});
```

**Result Data**

```
[ RowDataPacket { userId: 'arpitjindal97' },
  RowDataPacket { userId: 'cs01' },
  RowDataPacket { userId: 'samuelcolvin' },
  RowDataPacket { userId: 'Jyrno42' },
  RowDataPacket { userId: 'LemonyDesign' },
  RowDataPacket { userId: 'thruthesky' },
  RowDataPacket { userId: 'thruthesky' },
  RowDataPacket { userId: 'thruthesky' },
  RowDataPacket { userId: 'thruthesky' },
  RowDataPacket { userId: 'apollographql' },
  RowDataPacket { userId: 'samuelcolvin' },
  RowDataPacket { userId: 'Jyrno42' },
  RowDataPacket { userId: 'Jyrno42' },
  RowDataPacket { userId: 'thruthesky' }
}
```

I tried `console.log(Array.from(new Set(data)));` but the result is same.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try `distinct` to remove duplicate data

```
router.get(`/find-users/:queryString`, function(req, res, next) {
  let queryString = req.params.queryString;
  db.query(
    `SELECT distinct userId from project WHERE keyword like "%${queryString}%"`,
    function(error, data) {
      // console.log(Array.from(new Set(data)));
      console.log(data);
    }
  );
  res.json(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think about process in SQL !! works well.